# Using Unix/Bash, how can I make a lookup table?

Tags: bash, unix

So I have a .txt list of gene names and probe IDs, originalFile.txt, like so:

```
GENE_ID PROBE_ID
10111   19873
10112   284, 19983
10113   187
```

There are about 30,000 rows in this text file. I would like to create a new text file with no commas in the second column, like:

```
GENE_ID PROBE_ID
10111   19873
10112   284
10112   19983
10113   187
```

...but also, I want all of the PROBE_IDs to come from another text file, probes.txt, which looks like:

```
19873
284
187
```

...so that I can make a finalProduct.txt file that looks like:

```
GENE_ID PROBE_ID
10111   19873
10112   284
10113   187
```

If I wanted to type in each row of probes.txt by hand, I think I could achieve this result with something like:

```
awk -F"/t" '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){if ($i ~ /probeID#/){print $i}}}' myGenes > test.txt
```

But, of course, this wouldn't put the comma-separated probe IDs on different rows, and I would have to input each of the thousands of probeIDs by hand.

Does anyone have any hints or better suggestions?
Thank you!

**EDIT FOR CLARITY**
So I think there are two steps in what I'm asking. I'd like to take originalFile.txt and eventually produce finalProduct.txt, using probes.txt. There are two steps in this:

For each probe listed in probe.txt, find out if it exists in originalFile.txt;
if the probe does exist, then print a line that has just the probe and the corresponding GENE_ID.

or you could think of it as some kind of <strike>join between</strike> filter on originalFile.txt using probes.txt, where the output file has the PROBE_ID column as the probes in probes.txt and the corresponding GENE_ID from originalFile.txt.

or you could think of it as:
1. make an intermediate file where there is a many-to-one correspondence between GENE_ID and PROBE_ID
2. remove all of the rows of that intermediate file where the PROBE_ID does not correspond to an entry in probes.txt

**EDIT 2**
Currently trying to repurpose [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/110303/expanding-comma-separated-list-into-separate-lines) - no result yet, but maybe link will be helpful.

Comment: It's not clear how you want to match rows in probe.txt and rows on the other file (the first one). Also, it's not clear why the excerpt of finalProduct.txt does not contain two rows for gene 10112 while you seem to claim probe ids should go in different rows in at least two locations of your question.

Comment: So you mean you want to filter for probe IDs found in `probes.txt`? There's only one column there, so it's hardly a join.

Comment: I hope my edit makes it clearer. 10112 only appears once in finalProduct.txt because the corresponding PROBE_ID from probes.txt only appears once. In originalFile.txt, GENE_ID= 10112 corresponds to two PROBE_IDs: 284 and 19983. Only the PROBE_ID=284 appears in probes.txt. Therefore, in finalProduct.txt (in which all rows must correspond to a probe in probes.txt), there is only one entry - the entry corresponding to PROBE_ID=284.

Comment: And yes, I would like to create a filter. I know it's not something I could do with join - I was referencing the idea that if I had a sorted, straightforward probe list that I could join it with originalFile.txt (with a sorted second column) to get something like what I want for finalProduct.txt . Unfortunately, I can't do anything so simple because of the comma-separated probes in originalFile.txt (and because, as you say, there is only one column - PROBE_IDs - in probes.txt)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If `probes.txt` is small enough that it will fit in memory, you could try the following `awk` script:

```
BEGIN {
    OFS="\t";
    # this is to handle the given input that has spaces after the comma
    # and tabs between gene and probes
    FS="[\t, ]+";
    # load probes into an array
    while ((getline probe < "probes.txt") > 0) {
        probes[probe] = 1;
    }
    close ("probes.txt");
}

{
    # for each probe, check if it's in the array
    # and skip it if not
    for (i=2; i <= NF; i++) {
        if (probes[$i] == 1) {
            print $1, $i;
        }
    }
}
```